# jQuery AJAX is stripping out inline CSS from HTML data

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, inline

I am trying to pass HTML data to the server via AJAX. I ultimately want to store the full HTML code, including any inline CSS definitions, in a database. I don't want to make any changes to the HTML data, just store it as-is. My problem is that when I pass HTML data through AJAX, when it reaches the server the inline CSS has been stripped out, but not only that, it was stripped out incorrectly leaving invalid HTML behind.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
var the_html = {'html':'<p><span style="font-size:42px;"><span style="color:#f00;">
    Some text</span></span></p>'};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: the_html,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

When the data reaches the server it looks like this:

```
<p><span>span style="color:#f00;">Some Text</span></span></p>
```

It seems to me like the jQuery tried to strip all of the inline CSS out, but screwed up with the first span tag by also removing the opening angle bracket of the second span tag. I tried escaping the data before sending it through AJAX, but the results were the same. Also, I am using the object literal syntax because I have a lot more data to pass than in the example and I want it to be an associative array when it gets to the server.

I don't want the inline CSS stripped out at all. I want all of the markup plus any CSS to be sent to the server intact. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try using json.stringify?

Comment: I tried called JSON.stringify on the data, but the server side tells me that there are "Disallowed characters" in the request.

Comment: What about `escape()` function of javascript?

Comment: The escape() function has no impact on what the server side receives. No matter what I try, the inline css is being incorrectly stripped.

Comment: maybe I missed it but it seems you haven't set content-type as JSON in your ajax request...it'll default to url encoded form.

Comment: I just 'POST-ed' your html in an internal system that I have created that utilized jquery AJAX and it worked just fine. I am sending simple post data (key-values) in `escape()` and it works fine. I'm guessing it's having a malformed data being sent. Try intercepting the post packet to see what is sent and in what format...Firebug is a good choice IMO

Comment: Why not use Base64 encode/decode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace style with style1( or anything) on javascript/frontend
 and again on server-side replace it back  from style1 to style

example:

> $.ajax({
>                                    url:base_url+'/adminevent/dragDrop',  data:{pid:p_id,content:data.replace('style','style1'),update:'update'},
>   type:'POST', success:function(res){ //alert(res)
>                                          } });

On serverside(its PHP for me):

> str_replace('style1','style',$content)